# android javax.xml.bind gson and @XmlSchemaType

Tags: java, android, jaxb, gson

I have an xsd provided by a client I can't change. I'm using jaxb to generate the classes. The resulting class has an annotation like:

```
@XmlSchemaType(name = "dateTime")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar expires;
```

I try to turn this into json using GSON and I get a classnotfoundexception for javax.xml.bind.XmlSchemaType.  I add the dependency for javax.xml.bind in maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.xml.bind</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-b54</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I get this crazy error:

> Attempt to include a core class (java.* or javax.*) in something other
>   than a core library. It is likely that you have attempted to include
>   in an application the core library (or a part thereof) from a desktop
>   virtual machine. This will most assuredly not work. At a minimum, it
>   jeopardizes the compatibility of your app with future versions of the
>   platform. It is also often of questionable legality.
>
> If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
>   appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine distribution,
>   as opposed to compiling an application -- then use the
>   "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
>
> If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact building an
>   application, then be forewarned that your application will still fail
>   to build or run, at some point. Please be prepared for angry customers
>   who find, for example, that your application ceases to function once
>   they upgrade their operating system. You will be to blame for this
>   problem.
>
> If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a core
>   package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to repackage
>   that code. That is, move the classes in question into your own package
>   namespace. This means that they will never be in conflict with core
>   system classes. If you find that you cannot do this, then that is an
>   indication that the path you are on will ultimately lead to pain,
>   suffering, grief, and lamentation.

!!!

I either need to skip the annotation, tell jaxb not to generate themor gson to ignore them or import the dependency correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

fixed me up - i wasn't aware that everything under javax.* is provided by android.